# How should I respond to internal errors in SaaS products? Is it acceptable to suggest contacting customer support as an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

These days (supported) [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)/[PaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) software and managed solutions are becoming more predominant in the world of programming.

As a result I am frequently seeing questions that effectively can be reduced to:

> I am seeing an internal error without any other information. What should I do?

In this case there is often no access to logs or more information without contacting support.
Additionally, unless support gets contacted they cannot improve the product, or at least make the error message more detailed.

Often it is also mentioned in the error itself that one should contact support if the problem persists.

Here is an example: [How to debug internal errors in Google Vertex AI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75019596/how-to-debug-internal-errors-in-google-vertex-ai)

Though this question does not contain the full reproducible input many similar ones do, I picked this one because the title so clearly suggests that the asker is aware of the situation.

Hence my question:

#### In case of internal errors on a supported black box solution, is it OK to answer that users should contact support?

Considerations:

- In situations where the user has a reasonable alternative path, where they gather information themselves, then I believe that is typically the recommended direction. However, often there is no such path available.
- It is possible to comment rather than answer, however comments are not intended to contain the solution to a problem.
- Perhaps users should not be permitted to ask this kind of question in the first place, but that also feels a bit weird. After all they have a reproducible error.

Comment: If it is really an issue that only support can solve, close the question for that reason. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @rene making that determination accurately without knowing the answer can be quite difficult, though.  I've definitely seen questions closed as support issues when a workaround could be found; a real support-only issue might be something like "Why is X a policy violation?", "Why has my account been frozen?" etc.

Comment: @rene what would be the recommended close reason in this case? Especially if the problem is reproducible?

Comment: Sometimes, when I feel like chances for a public answer are slim, I comment and ask if they have contacted support of said service already and what their answer was, basically framing it as part of the research that a question should perform beforehand. I often add that the maintainers of the service likely know best what a certain error means.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin community specific reason -> not about programming, I would say. The fact that support needs to be contacted makes it not a programming issue (yet).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> In case of internal errors on a supported black box solution, is it OK to answer that users should contact support?

**Recommending contacting support is an acceptable answer if you know that *the specific issue requires assistance from support* in order to solve, and *you explain why*.**  For example, if there are multiple possible causes of the error, and no good way to tell which it is without contacting support, then explaining that would be the best solution to a problem that other people might encounter.

The reason why a specific explanation is required is that there are people (often, I think, working for the company) who go around to almost every question on a given topic suggesting contacting support, and that's *really* not useful (we've had an ongoing series of attempts to get one company to stop doing this). [**Answers should be specific to the question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/165261) and not just generic form responses.

This also presumes that **the question itself is not a support question**.  Examples of support questions are things like "why was my app banned?", "would this violate the acceptable use policy and lead to me getting banned?", "why is the credit card on my account being declined?", etc.  These are all questions where it is clear, without any specific knowledge of the product, that there is no way that anyone who does not work for the company could answer it. (see also [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745))

With reproducible errors that describe how they occur, **it is possible that there is a solution or workaround** that someone else with the same issue has discovered.  That would be something that they could post as an answer to the question that would help others encountering the issue.

Comment: I would also add service outages to the list of unsupported questions. We keep some of them, but only for duplicate closure reasons

Comment: "if you know that the specific issue requires assistance from support in order to solve" That is probably the difficult step. I think it's impossible to know that with certainty. It could always be that there is a solution or workaround somewhere. A practical way might be to wait a bit and then suggest contacting support in a comment. I feel like a true answer cannot just be a referral to somewhere else.

Comment: @Trilarion Consider an answer like "This error means your account has been locked; contact support to get it unlocked."  Perhaps I should improve the phrasing a bit - I'm referring to cases where contacting support is part of a question-specific solution, with reasoning for why; it's not necessarily that it's the *only* possible way to solve it.  The goal is mainly to avoid generic solutions to contact support, since support can theoretically address virtually any issue.

Comment: This is opening a door that should stay closed. An answer that is elsewhere is not a SO answer. Nor is informing someone that they should go seek it.

Comment: @philipxy You are misunderstanding what I'm trying to say (perhaps I really do need to improve the phrasing).  In the scenarios I describe, contacting support **is** the answer.  The solution, the way to solve the problem, is to contact support and get them to do something, because that is the way that the problem is solved.  This is _very different_ than telling someone to _ask support how to solve the problem_, which is not and will never be a valid answer here.